# document fragments and appending children

Tags: javascript, dom, fragment, children

I'm new to the concept of document fragments and I am currently having some trouble figuring out how to append children to a fragment.

This is my html

```
<form>
  <ul id="tweets">
    <li><img src="tweetIcon.jpg"><span>This is my tweet</span></li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Below is my script:

```
var tweets = [
    "When teaching math, it shouldn't just be: 'Answer this question:'. It should also be:      'Question this answer:'",
    "Another reason to choose ",
    " Excellent! I love the new APIs that came with it, as well as the new tags and attributes.",
    "That's great. I am really grateful for your program and will definitely continue to encourage folks to enroll in courses!"
    ];

  function init() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("tweets");
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
    var tweet = tweets[i];
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerHTML = tweet;
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("src", "tweetIcon.jpg");
    li.appendChild(span);
    ul.appendChild(li);
    fragment.appendChild(img);
    fragment.appendChild(li);
    }
    ul.appendChild(fragment);
  }
```

Right now I see the img and the span element only once at the top of the list. Below are all the strings for the tweets correctly displayed as a list. I need to add the image and the span element to each tweet. The three lines that are commented out are where I attempted to add the image to each li element as a child, but those lines don't really do anything. Any suggestions? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `document.createElement("img")` inside the loop, otherwise you're repeatedly moving and changing the same image object.

Comment: thanks i edited my code above. I'm still having trouble with the span element though. right now it holds the text from the variable tweet but it shows up underneath each twitter icon image, and what I want it to do is show up beside it like the span element in the html.

Comment: Append the image to the li, then append the span to the li, then append the li to the ul. The computer isn't going to guess the order you meant.